# 414 The requested URL is too large to process

Tags: google-app-engine, http-post

I have a Google app engine game which deals with coordinates. During a save game operation, I am passing coordinate pairs to my python GAE servers. This is a post. I have started getting this error...

```
Google
414. That’s an error.
The requested URL /api/... is too large to process. That’s all we know.
```

It sounds like this might be an error with urls on ANY Google servers. Does anyone know of a resolution, or have a recommendation of how to work around this?

Desperately,
Nate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can pass the coordinates as post data, instead of part of the URL. Rookie discovery I guess. My code went from...

```
function callSaveMap(mapjson){
    $.post('/api/?a=map.save&j=' + mapjson, handleMapSave);
}
```

... to...

```
function callSaveMap(mapjson){
  var postData = {
    a: 'map.save'
    , j: mapjson
  }
    $.post('/api/', postData, handleMapSave);
}
```